# Force mouse wheel scroll on last section

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, scroll

I am building a wordpress page using uncode theme and set the pages to scroll to section. However, when I get to the last section which is more than the height of the window, it stops scrolling using my mouse wheel.

How can I force this specific div which is only the last section to scroll as I wanted?

URL: https://powerfulpoints.com.au/SITE_2017/#6

Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: You mean if your at the bottom of the page you can't scroll up?

Comment: @Steven, not necessarily on the bottom, if you try to view the link I included, when you arrive on the New Projects section. You still have the capability to scroll towards the footer, unfortunately, it doesn't seem to scroll down using the mouse wheel but instead, you have to move the scroll bar manually for it to scroll down.

Comment: Yes I tried the link but I don't see I could scroll more to the bottom. What I find out is want to scroll up bu that wasn't possible. You are also right you can't scroll down. You need to use the scrollbar. Can you show what for Jquery code you are using to do that?

Comment: Hi @Steven, it's built with the theme that you can find here: https://powerfulpoints.com.au/SITE_2017/wp-content/themes/uncode/library/js/app.js?ver=1761741573

It's using an 'isSectionscroller' variable.

Comment: @Steven, I've also removed the jquery script I got that stops the section to scroll upward. Thanks for finding that out!

Comment: Yes the scrolling up is fixed but scrolling down still doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

The only reason what I can think of is that you can't scroll down is because:

You have the following code:

```
$(this).attr('data-section', index);
```

If you look at the #6 html code it looks like this:

```
<div data-parent="true" class="enabled-scroll row-container onepage-
section boomapps_vcrow" data-label="6" data-name="6" data-section="6">
```

You see that is has `data-section = 6`

But the footer doesn't have any `data-section`

So there is no way it will scroll down with that function because number 6 is the end.

There are 2 thing you can do:

- First thing is you can place the footer in to `data-section 6`
- Second thing you can do is create a `data-section 7`

If you have any other questions just ask.

Comment: Is there any script I can use to force it to scroll when I arrive on the last section?

Comment: With the var you showed me the only thinks I think you can do is this 
you can place the footer in to data-section 6
or you can do is create a data-section 7. Do you understand what I mean with Data-section 7 and 6?

Comment: Yep, i got your point. However, we're using a default footer which is also being used by other pages. I was hoping there can be another way to handle it maybe through script or something else. I'll try your solutions and keep you posted. Thanks!

Comment: Okey thanks let my know if it worked. One question can you write your own script files?

Comment: Yep, Steven. I just need to get the idea how the mousewheel stopped on a specific div even if it still has extra content below it. Thanks!

Comment: Because you work with sections and those sections have an attribute data-section . And your footer hasn't got any attribute data-section. So the script thinks you are on the bottom because there aren't any data-section underneath data-section 6.